# Pro & Cons using dblink postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Can anyone suggest me what are the pros & cons of using dblink in Postgres?

I use dblink to connect to multiple database in my function in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dblink` is a great tool and it works very well.

The main cons are:

- If you run a query between 2 servers not on the same network you will have a lot of latency and the performance will be very degraded
- If you use `dblink` in a `JOIN`, in order to process this `JOIN` a lot of rows will have to be transferred from the remote server which will use bandwidth and degrade performance

If you have the possibility to use a single database for each query and not use multiple databases with `dblink` it will always be a better option.

Read also this interesting thread: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/dblink-performance-td5056145.html

Comment: You're much better off using foreign data wrappers, where some degree of condition pushdown/pullup through joins is supported in newer Pg versions.

Comment: Yes, foreign data wrappers that i know is i don't need to initiate connection every time i want query data, but in my case, my client database can be more than 1 (depends on number of client).